# Clustering of temperature and precipitation courses. Searching for approach

Tags: r, mixed-model, clustering, functional-data-analysis, model-based-clustering

I would like to cluster not only single observations, but I would like to cluster all observations for temperature together as a temperature course. So the goal is to cluster the temperature courses.

This is what I mean by temperature course and precipitation cource:
[image]

The data:
I have monthly means for a year of temperature and precipitation. This observations were done for a specific grid point (e.g. City) which is described by latitude and longitude. So for one grid point I have 12 measurements for temperature and 12 for precipitation.

```
  Longitude Latitude Temperature_01 Temperature_02 Temperature_03 Temperature_04 
1 -34.59354 83.53125         -25.51         -24.77         -25.51         -20.30
2 -34.31229 83.53125         -25.56         -24.83         -25.56         -20.34 
3 -34.03104 83.53125         -25.60         -24.89         -25.61         -20.37
4 -33.74979 83.53125         -25.65         -24.95         -25.66         -20.40
5 -33.46854 83.53125         -25.64         -24.97         -25.69         -20.41
6 -33.18729 83.53125         -25.58         -24.95         -25.71         -20.39
```

The example data is only for 4 months and 6 grid points.

```
  Longitude Latitude precipitation_01 precipitation_02 precipitation_03 precipitation_04
1 -34.59354 83.53125       0.08544360       0.04857035       0.04763113       0.05574058
2 -34.31229 83.53125       0.08281145       0.04804337       0.04593866       0.05510716
3 -34.03104 83.53125       0.08028053       0.04769204       0.04424618       0.05460043
4 -33.74979 83.53125       0.07785086       0.04734072       0.04255370       0.05396701
5 -33.46854 83.53125       0.07633231       0.04734072       0.04158657       0.05422038
6 -33.18729 83.53125       0.07491500       0.04769204       0.04098212       0.05498048
```

For now, I have data in this order, the temperature and precipitations behind each other in one CSV table. 
Like (Longitude, Latitude, Temperature [1:12], Precipitation [1:12]).

So I have temperature and precipitation measurements, and I want to take them as temperature course and precipitation course for a grid point and cluster them. And this is my question, how can I cluster this, which approach can I use? Maybe I need to use a model first, like Mixed effect models?
I would appreciate any information.

Comment: Your data is so-called "functional data". Searching for "functional data clustering" may be helpful. Unfortunately, there [does not appear to be much information on CV on this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-data-analysis+clustering).

Comment: +1 to what Stephan said but that being said, I would suspect that the thread on [How to consider different samples in functional data clustering?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212037) would answer most the issues raised here. If that is not the case, I would be happy to help with any particulars.